# Accessing unnamed tags in sub-elements of ElementTree

Tags: python, python-2.7, elementtree

I've been reading questions and examples for two days straight now with no luck so I think it's about time I ask my own question. I have a subset of the XML I'm working with attached.

I am looking to be able to get the values of the `<value><text></value></text>` sub elements but I have been unable to do so as of yet.

```
    #This is an example of the data retrieved via the REST call in my code.
    <results>
        <result offset='0'>
            <field k='_bkt'>
                <value><text>_internal~12~5A0B5349-F3B5-46CD-83E0-3816A0969D51</text></value>
            </field>
            <field k='_cd'>
                <value><text>12:241565</text></value>
            </field>
            <field k='_eventtype_color'>
                <value><text>none</text></value>
            </field>
            <field k='_indextime'>
                <value><text>1547138402</text></value>
            </field>
            <field k='_kv'>
                <value><text>1</text></value>
            </field>
        </result>
    </results>

    result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    data = result.read()

    tree = ET.fromstring(results)

    for leaf in tree:
        #just a txt file to dump output to
        info_f.write("Row: " + leaf.get('offset') + "\n")
        fields = leaf.findall('field')
        for field in fields:
            if 'k' in field.attrib:
                key = field.get('k')
                info_f.write("    Key: " + key + "\n")
```

The above code and sample data correctly outputs the offset as '0' and the named tags correctly, but I've tried a number of things to access the values of the sub elements with no luck.

Ideally my output would look like:

```
    Offset: 0
    key: _indextime
    value: 1547138402
    etc...
```

---

Edit: I have successfully accessed the elements using getchildren() in the following code snippet, which is deprecated in newer versions of python. Is there a more forward thinking, elegant approach?

```
    result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    data = result.read()

    tree = ET.fromstring(results)

    for leaf in tree:
        #just a txt file to dump output to
        info_f.write("Row: " + leaf.get('offset') + "\n")
        fields = leaf.findall('field')
        for field in fields:
            if 'k' in field.attrib:
                key = field.get('k')
                info_f.write("    Key: " + key + "\n")

                values = field.getchildren()                    
                for v in values:
                    temp = v.getchildren()                        
                    for t in temp:
                        info_f.write("    value: " + t.text + "\n")
```

Comment: The title is a bit odd. The tags are not "unnamed".

Answer (score 0):

You can get the values directly via [`findtext()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findtext).

```
for field in fields:
    if 'k' in field.attrib:
        key = field.get('k')
        value = field.findtext("value/text")
        info_f.write("    Key: " + key + "\n")
        info_f.write("    value: " + value + "\n")
```